# A form with datagridview inside a panel gathering data from another form - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an application which actually works showing different forms(sells, budgets, etc). Some of the forms manage datagridviews with content that the user selects from a database, and it is usually passed from a form to another, hiding the previous form and showing the following.
Now I would like to avoid forms popping up and hiding them, and build the app behavior in a panel, in which all forms are showed up. The thing is, I made this class to show forms in the panel:

```
public void openChildForm(Form childform)
        {
            if (activeForm != null)
                activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = childform;
            childform.TopLevel = false;
            childform.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childform.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel2.Controls.Add(childform);
            panel2.Tag = childform;
            childform.BringToFront();
            childform.Show();
            
        }
```

My problem relies here: how can I manage to pass the datagrid values from one form to another with this class, since I was working with ShowDialog forms. All datagridview values are passed like this:

```
                Sells cp = new Sells();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow rowww in dgvBudget.Rows)
                {
                    int rowID = cp.dgvSell.Rows.Add();
                    DataGridViewRow row = cp.dgvSell.Rows[rowID];
                    double qty = Convert.ToDouble(rowww.Cells[1].Value);
                    double price = Convert.ToDouble(rowww.Cells[2].Value);
                    double final = qty * price;
                    row.Cells[0].Value = rowww.Cells[0].Value;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = rowww.Cells[1].Value;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = price;
                    row.Cells[3].Value = final;
                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(discount.Text))
                    {

                        cp.subtotal.Text = this.subtotallbl.Text;
                        cp.totalLbl.Text = this.subtotallbl.Text;
                    }
                    else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(discount.Text))
                    {
                        cp.subtotal.Text = this.subtotallbl.Text;
                        cp.descuentoFinal.Text = this.discount.Text;
                        cp.totalLbl.Text = this.totalLbl.Text;
                    }
                }
```

Important: the application now works inside a panel, and I would like to work all forms from this panel, which allows me to reduce opened forms.

Comment: Would a `TabControl` work for this? Then you only need 1 `Form`.

Comment: *behavior in a panel, in which all forms are showed up* - note this wheel has already been invented; it's called MDI

Comment: *All datagridview values are passed like this* - it would be better to switch to a databinding appraoch, pass the datatable to which the grid is bound, and when the other form (which does not have to be dialog) puts items in the table, they just appear in the grid automagically

Comment: It is possible but not recommended to host Forms in other containers. Use UserControls instead and show them in e.g. TabPages or maybe directly in the main forms hiding the inactive ones..

Comment: MDI is so 90s users will feel very young. Not really recommended..